# Hide menu bar permanently

Tags: menu-bar

Is there a way to hide the menu bar permanently, or at least to have it stay hidden when I switch between spaces?

(Unfortunately [Permanently hide menu bar](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/446928/permanently-hide-menu-bar) didn't get any answers, hope a solution was found in the mean time)

Comment: What, never? How will you use menu commands? Is this for one app, or all apps?

Comment: Mostly I'm annoyed that the "automatically hidden" menu bar is open whenever I'm switching back to a fullscreen space. Making the menu bar permanently hidden would work just as well; as the linked question mentions, there is always  fn+ctrl+F2 to manually open the menu. Even if I could just disable it for one app (my fullscreen terminal) though, I would be happy.